# Angular Single Select checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have the following HTML that has a checkbox inside of the ng-repeat

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="address in contactInfo.Addresses">
    <td>{{address.DisplayType}}</td>
    <td>{{address.AddressLine1}}</td>
    <td>{{address.AddressLine2}}</td>
    <td>{{address.City}}</td>
    <td>{{address.State}}</td>
    <td>{{address.Zip}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.ClientDefault" ng-checked="{{address.ClientDefault}}" ng-click="updateAddressSelection($index, contactInfo.Addresses)" />
    </td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-envelope-square"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I run the updateAddressSelection function which is

```
$scope.updateAddressSelection = function(position, address) {
  angular.forEach(address, function(address, index) {
    if (position != index) {
      address.ClientDefault = false;
    }
  });
};
```

It will not remove the checkbox from the original checkbox that was marked by default using the ng-checked. The json object that is repeating looks like this.

```
{
  "ID": 6,
  "DisplayType": "Other",
  "AddressLine1": "123 test st",
  "AddressLine2": "",
  "City": "madeupville",
  "State": "MO",
  "Zip": "63123",
  "AddressType": 3,
  "Linked": 0,
  "ClientDefault": "true",
  "HouseholdDefault": 0
}
```

How can I get the originally marked checkbox to be removed on click as well. Other than the default checkbox not being cleared this is working perfectly.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a detail, but if not, why are you building a radio button using checkboxes?

Comment: @Noppey the business area requesting the site wants them to be checkboxes or at least look like checkboxes looking for a CSS option as well

Answer (score 0):

Please write with what parameters You run **updateAddressSelection** method.